# cannot load such file -- lib/api grape in rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I am trying run **[grape gem](https://github.com/intridea/grape)** in my rails 3.2.3 app.

I'm following this tutorial:

http://martinciu.com/2011/01/mounting-grape-api-inside-rails-application.html

but I get this error:

```
cannot load such file -- lib/api
```

I have added the `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in my `application.rb` file.

Also I have added `require "lib/api"` to my `routes.rb` file

**What's missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was fixed.

This tutorial http://martinciu.com/2011/01/mounting-grape-api-inside-rails-application.html is misleading if you are new.

E.g., The file names inside **lib folder** and the **Module names** should match in ruby, so if you have `MyApp`, it should be in `lib/my_app.rb` and it should be on the load path.

the right way is:

```
#lib/my_app.rb
module MyApp
  class API < Grape::API
    prefix "api"
    resource "posts" do
      get do
        Post.all
      end
      get ':id' do
        Post.find(params[:id])
      end
    end

  end
end
```

You must add in your `config/application.rb` the next for autoload:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Last, you must add this to your **routes.rb** file:

**mount MyApp::API => "/"**

Thank you to [Daniel Doubrovkine](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ruby-grape/ixIvQ1nXduo)